# View laravel in heroku doesn't run correctly when first time deploy to heroku

Tags: laravel, vue.js, heroku

im new to laravel. so i just try to deploy app to heroku but seem it dont work correctly

[image: heroku]

but when i run local at 127.0.0.1:8000 it work fine
[image]

i already put Procfile, add Config Vars to heroku but still not work.
i don't know to fix this, please help me. thanks.
full code here if you need
https://github.com/salmanagustian/wedding-digital-invitation

Comment: I did not download your project, but seems your URLs are not right. Try pressing `F12` or right click anywhere and `inspect`, you need to open the browser console, so you can see any errors